# How to configure WCF Service to AutoStart in AppFabric when the services reside in the website root

Tags: wcf, iis, appfabric

I'm trying to configure my WCF services under WIndows Server 2008 R2's IIS and AppFabric to auto-start, but the steps listed at MSDN (here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677285(v=azure.10).aspx) are possible only when the services reside in an application, but in my case, the .svc files reside directly in the site root.

This way, the 'Configure WCF and WF...' shows as '...for Site' and do not show the options for auto-start, as it would do if the application were hosted under an application sub-folder.

Someone knows what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to edit IIS config file, located at C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
[image: sample config]

or with Configuration Editor as **Root Level** (!)
[image: sample config editor]

or finally use a appcmd script

```
appcmd.exe set config  -section:system.applicationHost/sites /[name='YourSite'].[path='/'].serviceAutoStartEnabled:"True" /[name='YourSite'].[path='/'].serviceAutoStartProvider:"Service" /[name='YourSite'].[path='/'].serviceAutoStartMode:"Custom"  /commit:apphost
```

This only for configuring web application to autostart. You will have others steps for each service.

Comment: I've already solved the problem a while ago with [this answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/403040/how-to-configure-wcf-service-to-autostart-in-appfabric-when-the-services-reside) from the same question that i've posted at ServerFault.

But, you threw an unexpected light into the matter that was really useful in my case!